# C++ Error with overloading operator ==

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

The objects in my == function for some reason have the values 0 and i get a bad excess code in my comparison when I try to run the program try comparing two different objects. I don't know what i did wrong

In my main I have

```
#include "vector.h"
int main()
{

Matrix<int> A;//Assume all three objects have inital values beacuse thats not the main issue
Matrix<int> B;//
Matrix<int> D;//

if(A+B==A*D)
        cout<<"A+B==A*D is true"<<endl;
    else
        cout<<"A+B==A*D is false"<<endl;
}

In my header I have:

    #include<iostream>
    #include<fstream>
    #include<string>
    using namespace std;
    template <class T>
    class Matrix{
    public:
        Matrix();
        Matrix(T diagonal);

        template<class H>
        friend bool operator ==(const Matrix<H>& A,const Matrix<H>& B);

    private:
        const static int n=3;
        T a[n][n];


    };//class declaration

template <class T>

Matrix<T>::Matrix(){
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
        for (int j=0;j<n;j++)
            a[i][j]=0;
}
template <class T>

Matrix<T>::Matrix(T diagonal){
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
        for (int j=0;j<n;j++)
            if (i==j)
                a[i][j]=diagonal;
            else
                a[i][j]=0;
}

    bool operator ==(const Matrix<T> &A,const Matrix<T> &B)
    {

        int i,j;
        for(int i=0;i<A.n;i++)
            for(int j=0;j<B.n;j++)

                //cout<<"here's a: "<<A.a[i][j]<<endl;
                cout<<B.a[i][j]<<endl;
                if(A.a[i][j]!=B.a[i][j])//i get a bad access code and idk y
                {
                    return false;
                }


        return true;
    }
```

Comment: The code you showed looks good to me. Please provide an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org).

Comment: The problem is likely in your implementation of `Matrix<int> ::operator*` or `Matrix<int> ::operator+` (which you failed to include in your post). Make sure they are returning an object that will be valid after the operator returns.

Comment: @ Baum mit AugenWhat does SSCCE mean?

Comment: @guploo Follow the link and learn.

Comment: @guploo Click on the link.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious my * and + are def not wrong because I overloaded them and tested them and they worked fine

Comment: @guploo `my * and + are def not wrong`  Means nothing in the world of C++.  You can have code that seems to work, but is wrong and you're just lucky it is working (due to undefined behavior or some other reason).  Please post these functions.

Comment: This is awkward because it wasnt wrong actually. Apparently my results were supposed to be all true lol. But my question is why does cout<<B.a[i][j]<<endl; output 0?

Comment: @guploo Because `B.a[i][j]` *is* zero. If that is not supposed to happen, you have a bug.

Comment: @guploo You declare 3 `Matrix` objects in your `main` function, and all the values in the 2 dimensional arrays are set to 0 in each of these objects.   So I don't know what you expected to be printed but zero.  Is there more to your `main` than you're showing?